# Ion-toggle checked attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 with Angular 2 beta 11.

How do you **switch off** the toggle switch? Looking at the Ionic [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toggle/Toggle/), it suggests to use a `checked` attribute. However, I have tried this as well as `ng-checked` with no success.

Any suggestions please?

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Drivers Licence</ion-label>
  <ion-toggle checked="false" id="driversLicence" formControlName="driversLicence">Drivers Licence</ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems like if I have the `formControlName="driversLicence"`, the toggle switch is always on. Why is that? How can I get this to work because I need the `formControlName`?

I need to access the `driversLicence`, which I do as follows:

```
this.jobdetailsForm.value.driversLicence
```

OR

How can I get the `driversLicence` value without using a `formControlName` when the form submits? I try the following, but it is `null`.

```
document.getElementById('driverLicence')
```

Comment: It seems like if I have the `formControlName="driversLicence"`, the toggle switch is always on. Why is that? How can I get this to work because I need the `formControlName`?

Answer (score 2):

solved using `[(ngModel)]`. This ties it to the model object